# NodeJS Async Callback is Not Finishing & Rendering Handlebars Template

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, mongoose, callback

I've got an Express GET request that pulls data from a Mongoose query and for each `doc` returned, external functions perform calculations on each `doc` passed as `x` and return the results so I can render them on the front-end using Handlebars. Ideally, I would like to carry out my calculations `calcA, calcB, calcC, calcD` and then once they're completed for each of the documents, render the `test-env.hbs` template. Currently, the page doesn't render when I call it, in the logs, after some time, it shows `GET /test-env - - ms - -`, presumably because the callback gets stuck somewhere.

**Express GET Request**

```
var updates = require('./updates.js');
app.get('/test-env', function(req, res, next){
        Market.find({"marketname" : 'To Win'})
            .then(function(doc){
                async.forEach(doc, function(x, callback){
                    updates.calcA(x);
                    updates.calcB(x);
                    updates.calcC(x);
                    updates.calcD(x);
                }, function(err){
                    if(err)
                        return console.log(err);
                    res.render('test-env', {title: 'Test Page', items: doc});
                });
        });
    });
```

**Typical `calc` Function**

I want to add `returnA` and `returnB` to the `docs` data so I can render it in an `{{#each}}` expression in Handlebars

```
calcA: function(x) {
   Market.find({"student": x.student, "marketname": x.marketname})
    .sort({btotal: -1})
    .limit(1)
    .then(function(ret) {
      var valueA = ret[0].btotal;
      var valueB = ret[0].back;
      Market.find({"student": x.student, "marketname": x.marketname, "back": {$lt: valueB}})
      .sort({odds: -1})
      .limit(1)
      .then(function(doc) {
         var res = doc[0];
         if (res == null) {
           x.returnA = 0;
           x.returnB = 0;
         } else {
           x.returnA = res.back;
           x.returnB = res.btotal;
         }
     });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't calling your callback in your async iterator. If the `calc` functions are asynchronous, those callbacks should be handled individually. If they are not asynchronous, a normal `forEach` will do the trick.

```
            ...
            async.forEach(doc, function(x, callback){
                updates.calcA(x);
                updates.calcB(x);
                updates.calcC(x);
                updates.calcD(x);
                callback(); // Call the callback to move on to the next item
            }, function(err){
                if(err)
                    return console.log(err);
                res.render('test-env', {title: 'Test Page', items: doc});
            });
            ...
```

Comment: Hey carebdayrvis, the `updates.calc()` functions don't use any callbacks, they all consist of two nested mongoose calls using `.then(function(res1){})` for the outer mongoose query and `.then(function(res2){})` for the inner mongoose query. The order of execution of the `calc` functions doesn't matter, as long as the four complete before rendering the page. I have tried using your way and the page still doesn't load.

Comment: The `calcA` function you've provided is asynchronous. If you want that function to complete before rendering the page, you have to handle it asynchronously. One way would be with promises. 

Have a look at these: 
http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html 
http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you're not actually calling your callback function.

```
            async.forEach(doc, function(x, callback){
                updates.calcA(x);
                updates.calcB(x);
                updates.calcC(x);
                updates.calcD(x);
                // <--- callback() needs to go here.
            }
```

Look at: http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each
The example shows you need to explicitly call the callback() function.

By the way, do your calculations (and the callback function) depend on the order of the contents of the `doc` collection? Because the `async.forEach` method actually does not guarantee that each of the elements in `doc` are going to be calculated in the same order as they are in the collection. So if you are, then it's worth considering if an out of order calculation may result in a different result.

Comment: Hey Jty.tan, the `updates.calc()` functions don't use any callbacks, they all consist of two nested mongoose calls using `.then(function(res1){})` for the outer mongoose query and `.then(function(res2){})` for the inner mongoose query. The order of execution of the `calc` functions doesn't matter, as long as the four complete before rendering the page. I have tried using your way and the page still doesn't load.